# Azure Function VNET Issue with OnPremise path

Tags: azure-functions

I am facing quite weird issue, I have EP1 Service plan for Azure Functions and that Service Plan is connected to VNET through which we can connect to our on premise path using SFTP from Azure Function. It works fine when only one Azure Function is connecting to on premise path, but when I add multiple Azure Functions i.e for different Enviroments, I get this error from all of my functions:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Using Renci SFTPClient for connecting to onpremise path from C#.

Solution Structure is like this:

- Service Plan AA (EP1, Integrated with VNET)
- Azure Function A (Using SP AA)
- Azure Function B (Using SP AA)
- Azure Function C (Using SP AA)
- Azure Function D (Using SP AA)